# TDA2030 minimum operating voltage?

Tags: amplifier

According to the datasheet, the TDA2030 cannot operate with voltages below 6V.

I want to use this module with my power bank. Is there any chance that it will turn on?

It's the only module available on the website where I always get orders with enough output power in a suitable size.
I want to connect it to a Bluetooth module. [Could this all-in-one M38 module be better](https://www.optimusdigital.ro/en/wireless-bluetooth/8125-mh-m38-wireless-audio-transmission-module-ble-stereo-2-x-5-w.html) than a TDA2030 with an M18 Bluetooth module?

Comment: TDA2030 is guaranteed to work at 6V, that doesn’t mean that it won’t work below that but you’ll have to find out for yourself.  There doesn’t seem to be enough information on the M38 to say anything much about it.

Comment: The TDA2030 is **ancient** and not going to work very well at 5 V while that M38 module has everything you need and is designed for 5 V, it even has a USB connector. To me, the better choice is obvious, why is not to you? On paper the TDA2030 has more power output but that's not with a 5 V supply. Realize that at 5 V you will never get more output power than a few watts so use sensitive speakers.

Comment: You write that the TDA2030 has "enough output power" - but do you realize that you don't get anywhere near that power when you're only supplying it with 5 to 6V?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ok you are right, I'll pass TDA away, and use the all-in-one circuit .thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

The minimum voltage is not just 6V. Either it is 12V for a single supply, or dual supply of +6V and -6V for a total of 12V.

It is highly unlikely that it will work with single 5V supply, and even if it does work, the performance can be so poor that you don't want to use it at 5V.

Comment: ok that totally explained what I needed, thanks for the precise answer .